# styling a div in angularjs based on conditions

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

```css
.left {
    float: left;
}

.right {
     float: right;
}
```

```html
<div>
<div ng-repeat="x in myMessages">
    <div style="width:70%;" ng-class="{left: {{x.sender_username}} == '<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>', right: {{x.sender_username}} != '<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>'}">
    

        <strong>@{{x.sender_username}}</strong>
        <p>{{x.messages}}</p>


</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I am a building a chat app using angularjs, after logging in, the username of the user is set in session. On chatting with another user, I want the chat of the account owner to float to the left while the other person will float to the right, after searching online, this is what I came up with but not working. I will be happy to see someone to help with this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you really generate frontend templates with PHP? I am not curious, I am asking to answer correctly.

Comment: Can u  try `ng-style` in place of `ng-class` and let me know if you are getting what you want. `ng-class` is for different purpose, you are putting some style here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not put your hardcoded style into the classes now it is common anyway?

```css
.left {
  float: left;
  width:70%;
}

.right {
  float: right;
  width:70%;
}
```

Then, quote the class names and stop rendering. `ng-class` expects an expression:

```html
<div ng-class="{ 
  'left': x.sender_username == '<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>', 
  'right': x.sender_username != '<?php echo $_SESSION['username']; ?>'
}">
```